# Software architecture for two similar classes which require different input parameters for the same method

Tags: java, architecture, code-quality

I am writing Java code to simulate a supply chain.
The supply chain can be simulated in either
an intermediate stocking or a cross-docking configuration.
So, I wrote two simulator objects `IstockSimulator` and `XdockSimulator`.
Since the two objects share certain behaviors
(e.g. making shipments, demand arriving),
I wrote an abstract simulator object `AbstractSimulator`
which is a parent class of the two simulator objects.

The abstract simulator object has a method `runSimulation()`
which takes an input parameter of class `SimulationParameters`.
Up till now, the simulation parameters only contains fields
that are common to both simulator objects,
such as `randomSeed`, `simulationStartPeriod` and `simulationEndPeriod`.
However, I now want to include fields that are specific to the type of simulation that is being run,
i.e. an `IstockSimulationParameters` class for an intermediate stocking simulation,
and a `XdockSimulationParameters` class for a cross-docking simulation.

My current idea is take the method `runSimulation()`
out of the `AbstractSimulator` class,
but to put a `runSimulation(IstockSimulationParameters)` method
in the `IstockSimulator` class,
and a `runSimulation(XdockSimulationParameters)` method
in the `IstockSimulator` class.
I am worried however, that this approach will lead to code duplication.

What should I do?

#### Edited

Currently, the `AbstractSimulator` class defines the `runSimulation` method
which calls other abstract methods
that are only defined by the concrete child classes.

```
public abstract class AbstractSimulator {
    public void runSimulation(SimulationParameters params) {
        int startPeriod = params.startPeriod;
        int endPeriod = params.endPeriod;
        for (int t = startPeriod; t < endPeriod; ++t) {
            submitReports(t);
            makeShipments(t);
            demandArrives(t);
        }
    }
    protected abstract void submitReports(int t);
    protected abstract void makeShipments(int t);
}
```

One of the differences between the `IstockSimulator` and the `XdockSimulator`
is that in an intermediate stocking configuration,
tier 3 facilities submit reports to tier 2 facilities,
while in a cross-docking configuration,
tier 3 facilities submit reports to tier 1 facilities.
Thus the `IstockSimulator` and the `XdockSimulator`
have their own implementations of the methods `submitReports` and `makeShipments`.

#### What worked for me

Thank you for your answers.
Inspired by your answers, and after sleeping it over,
I came up with my own answer based on refactoring.
See below.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Edited to include detail that I am programming in Java.

Comment: I guess your real question is how to enforce type checking on the concrete classes' runSimulation() methods?

Comment: Indeed, I would like the concrete classes to perform type checking.

Comment: What did you end up doing？

Comment: @Alex I posted what I did as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by your answers,
and after sleeping it over,
I came up with a different and elegant solution
which involves refactoring the code.

I define a class `SupplyChain` which contains
information about the supply chain topology, the lead times for shipments, etc.
I define two different simulator classes `IstockSimulator` and `XdockSimulator`.
The replenishment policy and the simulation parameters (initial conditions)
are given to the `IstockSimulator` at the time of its creation.
Similarly for the `XdockSimulator`.
Thus there is only one `runSimulation` method
that takes in an input parameter of `SimulationParameters`.

This is what it looks like in Java code.

```
SupplyChain supplyChain = // create new supply chain
SimulationParameters simulationParameters = // define simulation parameters
IstockSimulator isim = new IstockSimulator(supplyChain,
    istockPolicies, istockInitialConditions);
isim.runSimulation(simulationParameters);
XdockSimulator xsim = new XdockSimulator(supplyChain,
    xdockPolicies, xdockInitialConditions);
xsim.runSimulation(simulationParameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `runSimulation()` method has to be defined in the concrete classes because it uses different parameters, so it follows that it behaves differently. If you have common functionality, I would put the `runSimulation()` method in the concrete class with no parameters. Any common functionality like utility/helper methods can go in the abstract class. The constructor, which is already implementation-specific, accepts the parameters.

Creating a new object for each simulation, using the constructor to pass in parameters, has two benefits. First, it sidesteps the interface issue. Second, it solidifies the idea that a simulation should only be run once (it may have internal state for example, so it might not be reentrant anyway).

If you change the design this becomes the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

```
public interface SimulationParameters { ... }

public interface Simulation<T extends SimulationParamters> {
  SimulationResult runSimulation();
}

public class StockSimulation implements Simulation<StockParameters> {
  public StockSimulation (StockParameters p) { ... }
}

public class DockSimulation implements Simulation<DockParameters> {
  public DockSimulation (DockParameters d) { ... }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Simulation s1 = new StockSimulation(new StockParameters());
Simulation s2 = new DockSimulation(new DockParameters());
```

You could then pass this off to an `Executor` or whatever else to run it, possibly in parallel. That is one of the advantages of this approach, it is very flexible.

This may avoid code duplication, and it *definitely* avoids polluting the interface which is I believe the real concern in your last paragraph.

#### Code Duplication

To avoid code duplication in the `runSimulation()` method, I would consider the approach of using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) to encapsulate each [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) step of a simulation in its own child object.

```
public interface SimulationComponent {
  void runStep(SimulationState state, ...);
}
```

Then, in your simulation class, you could have simulation components:

```
public class StockSimulation implements Simulation<StockParameters> {

  private final List<SimulationComponent> components;

  public StockSimulation (StockParameters p) {
    List<SimulationComponent> c = new LinkedList<>();
    c.add(new SimulationComponentImpl1());
    c.add(new SimulationComponentImpl2());
    c.add(new SimulationComponentImpl3());
    components = Collections.unmodifiableList(c);
  }

  public SimulationResult runSimulation() {
    SimulationState state = ...;
    for (SimulationComponent c : components) {
      c.runStep(state);
    }
    return state.getResult();
  }
}
```

Without detailed information about how the simulation works I cannot say for sure exactly how this code should work, but I believe this is the correct general approach.

Comment: ok you've put one angle of the question in code, but how would you reduce code duplication?

Comment: Break your simulation behaviour into modular classes. Share these between the two simulations and their base as appropriate. Composition > Inheritance.

Comment: Without more information about the internals I cannot say for sure if code duplication is a concern. However, if the parameters are different for each simulation, that tells me that the execution has to be different as well. How much different, I do not know: but using other objects to compose behavior is the correct approach as @MrCochese says. You may even be able to use a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to compose an object chain that makes the simulation "go." I will edit my answer to address this.

Answer (score 2):

> I am worried however, that this approach will lead to code duplication.

yes, it might.

> What should I do?

I suggest using generics. Like so

```
public abstract class AbstractSimulation<T extends SimulationParameters> {
    public void runSimulation(T parameters) {
        // common functionality
    }
}
public class SimulationParameters {
   // common parameters
}
public class StockSimulationParameter extends SimulationParameters {
   // specific parameters
}
public class StockSimulation extends AbstractSimulation<StockSimulationParameter> {
    @Override
    public void runSimulation(StockSimulationParameter parameters) {
        super.runSimulation(parameters); 
    }
}

// the same for XDockSimluation and XDocSimulationParameters
(... omitted for brevity ...)
```

If you do this, StockSimulation.runSimulation() will only accept StockSimulationParameters instances, but not SimulationParameters:

```
StockSimulation stocksim = new StockSimulation();
// not OK
SimulationParamters simparamCommon = new SimulationParamters();
stocksim.runSimulation(simparamCommon);
// OK
StockSimulationParameter simparam = new StockSimulationParameter(); 
stocksim.runSimulation(simparam);
```